# Convert nested dictionary to excel by key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary in the form:

```
{'2015':{'name':count1,name1:'count2'},
'2016':{'name':count3,name2:'count4'}}


pd.DataFrame(dict).T.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

My excel document has the nested dictionary in a cell

```
2015 {'name':count1,name1:'count2'}
```

I would like the excel to be like this instead

```
'2015'
'name':count1
name1:'count2

'2016'
'name':count3
name2:'count4'
```

Comment: It does not come in a single cell for me. There could be something wrong with your dictionary. Print the dataframe to see how it appears there.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data here, so we can work on it.